# How to add data in an empty dictionary in a function?

Tags: python

I know the title is weird, but my English skill isn't good enough to exactly explain my problem, so sorry for the poor title.

What I'm trying to do is, I want to change angles in decimal degrees into hour/minute/second.

I thought maybe I can make a function that receives an angle value and an empty dictionary to save the hour/minute/second value that I converted from the angle value.

After some research about putting a dictionary as a parameter, I ended up with this:

```
import numpy as np 

def deg2hms(deg, hour, minute, second):
    degree = deg
    hour = np.rint(degree / 15)
    minute = np.rint((degree - (hour * 15)) * 4)
    second = (degree - (hour * 15) - (minute / 4)) * 240


deg_data = 198.378178
data = {'hour' : 0, 'minute' : 0, 'second' : 0}

deg2hms(deg_data, **data)

print(data['hour'], "h", data['minute'], "m", data['second'], "s")
```

The result was

```
0 h 0 m 0 s
```

so I knew there was definitely something that I wasn't understanding correctly.

I started tinkering with python about a week ago, so I might be doing an elementary mistake, but I could not find any articles regarding my problem.

Comment: You aren't passing a dictionary to your function. You are *unpacking* your dictionary as an argument, and the individual values are being passed as keyword arguments. You never modify a dictionary anywhere in `deg2hms`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call a function with `f(**kwargs)` like that, you're passing in the dictionary keys as function argument labels (and their values as the corresponding values) and not a reference to the dictionary key.

One thing you could do is pass the dictionary directly as an argument and change your assignments to, e.g.

```py
data['hour'] = np.rint(degree / 15)
```

or you could return a dictionary of `{'hour':x, 'minute':y, 'second':z}` and call your function with

```py
data = deg2hms(deg_data)
```

Comment: I changed my function to return a dictionary and it works! Thanks a lot for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

The arguments to your `deg2hms` function are copies of the values in your `data` dictionary.  When they are changed in the function, that doesn't cause the values in the dictionary to change.

What I would do is have the function return a new dictionary containing the results of the conversion:

```
import numpy as np

def deg2hms(deg):
    degree = deg
    data = {}
    data['hour'] = np.rint(degree / 15)
    data['minute'] = np.rint((degree - (data['hour'] * 15)) * 4)
    data['second'] = (degree - (data['hour'] * 15) - (data['minute'] / 4)) * 240
    return data

deg_data = 198.378178

data = deg2hms(deg_data)

print(data['hour'], "h", data['minute'], "m", data['second'], "s")
```

Result:

```
13.0 h 14.0 m -29.2372800000021 s
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a beginner error, no problem with that.

In Python, there is a difference between *mutable* and *immutable* objects. Simple objects (numbers, strings and bytes strings) are immutable, most containers (lists, dictionnaries and sets) are mutable. But a tuple or a frozen set are immutable.

If you want to change something in a parameter passed to a function, the object must be mutable. And you must not assign to the passed variable but change its properties.

Here you could pass a list and append to it:

```
def change_lst(x):
    del x[:]               # clear the list
    x.extend([1, 2, 3])    # append the expected values

lst = []
change_lst(lst)
print(lst)
```

will give `[1, 2, 3]`.

But this:

```
def change_lst(x):
    x = [1, 2, 3]    # Oops not an error but will not change anything!
```

would not change `lst` because it just assign `x` which is a local variable in the function with a different object. This may not be the most simple part of Python, but just remember about *mutability* and make sure to run tests when you try to change an object passed to a function.

Comment: I did not know about the whole mutable/immutable thingy. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def deg2hms(deg ):
        rv = { "hour":0, "minute":0,"second":0}
        rv["hour"] = np.rint(deg / 15)
        rv["minute"] = np.rint((deg - (rv["hour"] * 15)) * 4)
        rv["second"] = (deg - (rv["hour"] * 15) - (rv["minute"] / 4)) * 240
        return( rv) 

deg_data = 198.378178
data = deg2hms(deg_data) 
print(data['hour'], "h", data['minute'], "m", data['second'], "s")
```